# How to permit cursor to leave left side of screen with dual monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I added an additional monitor to a Windows 7 laptop, so that I have 2 screens, Display 1 (laptop screen) and Display 2 (additional monitor). On my desk, the additional monitor has to sit to the left of the laptop. Therefore I would like to be able to move my cursor out of the *left* side of Display 1 and have it appear on the right side of Display 2. The default setup only permits the cursor to leave the *right* side of Display 1 and appear on the left side of Display 2, which is frying my brain.
**What settings allow the cursor to exit the left side of Display 1 and enter the right side of Display 2**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right-click on the desktop, choose `Screen Resolution` option, rearrange monitors in the display.

Comment: more details here: http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx

Comment: actually, in windows 10 you have to drag the screens to make another screen as main screen, take my 1 hour to figure it out,

Comment: Drag your screen 1 into opposite side of screen 2.

Comment: SWEET
AWESOMELOVELY

Comment: and click on Apply after you dragged the screens :( With the new web UX whitout save buttons, I forgot to Apply changes

Answer (score 3):

Go to the picture and select the monitor you want on the left. Move it to the left of the other monitor and hit apply.

Answer (score 2):

In your display settings (where you enable the second monitor) there is a graphical image of 2 monitors that you can actually drag and drop them into the position that you want.

The monitor settings initially show #1 on the left and #2 on the right. You can click and drag the number 2 monitor over to the left side of number 1. What that does is still makes the monitor in front of you #1 and the one to your left #2 but when the mouse moves across the screen it will make the correct exit and entry when going from one screen to the other.

This feature also works if your monitors are sitting one on top of the other or perhaps sitting corner to corner. In my setup, the second monitor sits about a half-screen lower than the other (because of how the desk is designed) and I moved the 2 monitors in the display settings in that configuration so when the mouse goes across the bottom of the main screen, it comes out in the middle of second screen (rather than jumping to the bottom) so visually it stays lined up.